.NET: console to on-demand receive and display fire-and-forget traces from other local application?
I'd like to create a small console application that, on-demand, for troubleshooting purposes, I can start to capture and display traces from another local client application. I've been considering numerous approaches some somewhat older such as posting  WM_COPYDATA messages (oldish and probably with a max size limit for messages), OutputDebugString (or .NET Trace class methods that also call this Windows function) + some filtering to recognize messages coming from the specific application, named or anonymous pipes (do not allow fire-and-forget tracing as a connection needs to be awaited between client and server), other IPC methods such as WCF or remoting (both not as lightweight as I'd like). Anyone able to suggest some lightweight and effective approach?

If you're interested in using such a utility rather than creating one yourself, you might consider the DebugView utility from Microsoft's SysInternals suite - it can capture OutputDebugString calls made from other applications.

I know and use DebugView. The console application I'd like to create is to be distributed together with the main application and it is meant as a quick troubleshooting utility for end users.

If you need to send traces to a consumer that may not be running, or accept from a provider that may not be running, consider a message queue. MSMQ and Kafka are available for local queues, AWS and Azure both have remote queues.

I suppose MSMQ and Kafka both require a local infrastructure to be available (MSMQ for certain since I've even used it time back to develop messaging solutions). I'm really looking for something lightweight and with no dependencies on external services that might not be there on end-users computers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/etw-tracing

I've implemented use of WM_COPYDATA messages and it works very reliably with messages always all received. In terms of performance, I'm able to receive 100k messages of 1k bytes in just above 34 seconds.
Here is an overview of a good part of the IPC options existing on Windows machines (COM, data copy, DDE, file mapping, mailslots, pipes, RPC, sockets). What I implemented is listed in the article as "data copy for IPC". Other options such as WCF, remoting and OutputDebugString are not listed.
